# Magento: How to show custom attribute on product page below description

Tags: magento

I have a custom attribute for products in which I add a video URL.
I made this Embed video responsive using css.

Now I want to call the custom attribute on the product page, so it shows the video.

The file responsible for this is: description.phtml

I've tried the following:

```
?>
<?php $_description = $this->getProduct()->getDescription(); ?>
<?php if ($_description): ?>
<h2><?php echo $this->__('Details') ?></h2>
<div class="std">
    <?php echo  $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), $_description, 'description') ?>
</div>
<div class="std">
    <?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('video') ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttributeText() on a non-object in /data/web/public/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/description.phtml on line 40
```

The video does show however. I'm probably doing this all wrong. Can I fix this with a simple edit of the code, or do I have to use an entirely different approach?

Thanks.

Comment: Where does $_product comes from, has it been initialized ? It seems you use $this->getProduct() above instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo $this->getProduct()->getAttributeText('video'); ?>
```

Try this. Or on top of document add this

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
```

Comment: Try this `<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); $_description =  $_product->getDescription(); ?>
<?php if ($_description): ?>
<h2><?php echo $this->__('Details') ?></h2>
<div class="std">
    <?php echo  $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute( $_product, $_description, 'description') ?>
</div>
<div class="std">
    <?php echo $_product->getData('video') ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>`